# how can I use foreachbatch to report microbatch size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a current spark job that looks something like this (written in pyspark). All it does is read from an S3 location, and write a delta location to another s3 location (s3_delta_path). I would like to modify this slightly to use the "foreachbatch" pyspark function in order to insert some additional logic to track progress. Specifically, every time it writes a batch, i just want to compute the size of that batch and write the result somewhere else. Other than that, I want the core logic of the transfer job to remain unchanged. How can I achieve this?

````
df.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation",
s3_checkpoint_path).trigger(availableNow=True).start(s3_delta_path)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. You can modify processBatch function as needed.

```
def processBatch(batch_df, batch_id):
  print(batch_id,batch_df.count(),batch_df.columns())
  
  #batch_df.count() -- returns the number of rows
  #batch_df.columns() -- returns the number of columns
  batch_df.write.....
  


df.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(processBatch)
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation",s3_checkpoint_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .start()
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? I got an error when I did this. I think start doesnt take an argument when using foreachbatch, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted the start() as is, fixed it now. Refer to this page for a detailed example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/examples#write-to-azure-synapse-analytics-using-foreachbatch-in-python